# how do i send response every 10s?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

When I call API, I need to take data from the database every 10s and send it to the frontend.

```
router.get("/get",  function (req, res){
          cron.schedule("*/10 * * * * *",  async()=>{
            const alldta =  random.find({});
            const data = await alldta.exec();
            console.log(data);
            res.send(data);
          });
});
```

Comment: One of the ways is to have frontend request the data every 10s (AKA "short polling")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be done like this. If you want this functionality, look into [Sockets](https://socket.io/). A request can only send data once, and a socket can keep sending data.

**EDIT:**
Another option is to keep sending requests to the server, but that might have a bigger impact on performance.

Comment: It can be done, though. I'm not a node.js guy, but cursory googling suggests that express supports streaming responses. This will likely need additional handling on the client-side and overall may be too much work for too little gain compared to, say, short-polling, but it is possible.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Fair point, it is possible, but most http clients (frontend) I know don't like streaming since they will wait for the last package or part of stream to be received.